# SDK and AVD Manager will not start virtual device

Tags: android, adt, ubuntu-11.04

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 64bit, Eclipse 3.5.2, and Android Development Toolkit 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431

The "SDK and AVD Manager" dialog from the "Windows" menu seems to have a problem starting any emulators I have created; it does nothing when the "Start..." button is clicked.

I can start an emulator fine from the terminal, but I'd like to stay in eclipse and have it scaled down before I begin testing my application.

I've tried re-installing Eclipse, to no avail.

Any help, advice, or info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround, but you can perfectly start your emulator outside Eclipse and use it from Eclipse: ADT communicates with it using a network connection to localhost:5554 by default.

There is a [command-line option](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) called `-scale` that allows scaling the virtual device. It accepts a factor between 0.1 and 3, a dpi value or the keyword `auto` to let the emulator to chose a size for you (which is not necessarily the actual size of a physical device).

About the Eclipse integration problem, it's difficult to have an idea. You don't see any error message?

Comment: No error message or anything. Just kind of stalls when "Start..." button is clicked.

Comment: Wow. No idea in that case. Being in front of the machine would help :)

Comment: And for some reason that scale option from command-line completely screws up the emulator; colors become saturated/inverted, its impossible to see the screen.

Comment: It seems there is an installation issue or a compatibility issue somewhere. Sorry that I cannot help you on this.

Comment: Hi Brandon, did you ever resolve this issue. I have the same in Ubuntu